# Is it possible to use request header as a parameter inside FaunaDB user defined function (UDF)?

Tags: header, user-defined-functions, abac, faunadb

Can I get the header's value somehow inside the UDF's body?

The idea is to implement our own ABAC based on custom header parameters (like userId, role, key, UDF, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fauna queries do not have access to request headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fauna to generate Tokens that you can use in your headers for querying data. While creating user you will create a username/email and a password that will be stored as a "credential". You can create a login UDF and a user_by_email index which will verify user and issue a token.
The login UDF looks something like this:

```
Query(
  Lambda(
    ["data"],
    Create(Collection("User"), {
      credentials: { password: Select("password", Var("data")) },
      data: {
        firstName: Select("firstName", Var("data")),
        lastName: Select("lastName", Var("data")),
        email: Select("email", Var("data")),
        role: Select("role", Var("data")),
        phone: Select("phone", Var("data")),
      }
    })
  )
)
```

And the user_to_email index will look like this:

```
Source Collection: User
Index Name: user_by_email
Terms: data.email
Values: Serialized: true
```

Here is a link to Fauna's User Authentication document: https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/tutorials/authentication/user.html

Hope this helps.